# Rendering files efficiently with php / apache

Tags: php, apache

I am developing a website where users can upload images.

The users should only be allowed to see the images when they are logged in.

I can see that Facebook is doing that by rendering private photos through photo.php like this:

```
<img src="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10231522709593244&set=a.10150407561663244.3514699.73368243&type=1">
```

I can do the same thing like this:

photo.php:

```
if ($user_logged_in)
{
    $filename='/home/protectedfolder/'.$_GET['fbid'].'.jpg';   // you got the idea...
    header("content-type: image/jpg"); 
    header('Expires: 0');                    
    readfile($filename);        
}
```

...and it works, but it is VERY SLOW, even though the server is very powerful.

How can I do this in a more efficient way? I have tried with file_get_contents and cURL, but that did not help. I have also tried to enabled cashing but it seems to be ignored.

Do I need to change apache configuration or do I need extra apache modules?

Comment: When loaded directly, is the image loading fast?

Comment: yes, they are loaded very fast when "normal" img tags are used.

Comment: and when you manually access photo.php its slow?

Comment: The server is fast in general... it is a expensive VPS solution.

Comment: This is FAST:
<img src='images/hugeimage.jpg'>

Comment: This is SLOW:
<img src='photo.php?fBid=12'>

Comment: How about http://yourdomain.com/photo.php?fBid=12 ?

Comment: `readfile` should be as fast as directly accessing the file. However, you could also try a header redirect instead of a readfile. This would introduce a security hole as files need to be public then.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using PHP to add css values (fig. 1) to your head if a user is or is-not logged in, then add a script (fig. 2) to your `.htaccess` to prevent other sites from showing your images.

This should me much faster than trying to have PHP read the file.

**fig 1:**

```
<head>
...
<?php
if(!$is_logged_in) {
echo '<style>.private_image { display:none; }</style>';
}
</head>
```

**fig 2:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

---

Also:

It may be a good idea to just remove or replace the image tags on the page rather than a CSS value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have output buffering enabled.

Try this to disable the buffering:

```
if ($user_logged_in)
{
    $filename='/home/protectedfolder/'.$_GET['fbid'].'.jpg';   // you got the idea...
    header("content-type: image/jpg"); 
    header('Expires: 0');                    
    ob_end_flush();
    readfile($filename);        
}
```

Output buffering means, the server caches the whole data in memory before sending it to the browser.